# PHP logical operators "&&" and "||" while building simple security function

Tags: php

A few days ago I started implementing simple security function to my project to prevent users from viewing customers added to database by other users. When I was doing this, I got confused because I realized that standard logical operators works in weird way.

This is the code I initially wrote:

```
if($current_user_id != $session_user_id || access_level($session_user_id) != 3) {
    header('Location: logout.php');
    exit();
}
```

It means that if stored customer that you are trying to view doesn't belong to You or Your access level isn't 3 (administrator) you will be logged out. It should work according this:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp

They say that `||` means "True if either condition 1 or condidtion 2 is true", so if any of conditions doesn't fail it should allow access. Of course it isn't, script behave as only first condition is written, meaning if you are admin so your access level is 3 and you are viewing not your customer - you still will be logged out.

This is minor modification that started to work:

```
if($current_user_id != $session_user_id && access_level($session_user_id) != 3) {
    header('Location: logout.php');
    exit();
}
```

After switching to `&&` which means "True if both condition 1 and condition 2 are true"
it started to work correctly, meaning you might not be owner of customer but if you are admin you will be allowed to access and not logged out.

At this point I'm afraid I understand it backwards, could someone explain why it doesn't seem logical? And how exactly it works? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your best bet is to try to figure out what the variables actually contain. Try doing `var_dump($current_user_id); var_dump($session_user_id); var_dump(access_level($session_user_id));` and manually work your way through the logic.

Comment: Check this out: [PHP Logical Operators](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php3p10.html)

Comment: I hope you are properly verifying the result of your MySQL queries to avoid comparing user id `0` to `null` or false with `==`. For example given you assign the result of your MySQL direct to a variable without checking weather it failed or not it could result on that variable being false or null and resulting on a true match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your logic is that the user should be allowed access if:

- They are the owner, OR
- The are an administrator

By this logic, you might construct this statement:

```
if( $user == $owner || access_level($user) == 3) {
    // allow access
}
```

But you're using the negative position, ie. disallowing access if they are NEITHER the owner NOR an administrator. This means you have to negate the entire `if` statement.

Looking at the truth tables for `||` and `&&`:

```
A B A||B A&&B
0 0  0    0
0 1  1    0
1 0  1    0
1 1  1    1
```

You can see from this that in order to get the opposite of `A||B`, we need `!A && !B`:

```
A B !A !B A||B !A&&!B
0 0 1  1   0     1
0 1 1  0   1     0
1 0 0  1   1     0
1 1 0  0   1     0
```

So to write this, you do the following:

```
if( !($user == $owner) && !(access_level($user) == 3) ) { /* deny access */ }
```

Which can of course be written as:

```
if( $user != $owner && access_level($user) != 3) { /* deny access */ }
```

Comment: Thank You mate, great explaining!

Answer (score 3):

This:

> it means that if stored customer that you are trying to view doesnt belong to You or Your access level isnt 3 (administrator) you will be logged out.

Does not entail this:

> if any of conditions doesnt fail it should allow access

See [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

The first statement is essentially `(!a || !b)`. Negating that (i.e., `!(!a || !b)`) actually switches to operator to become: `(a && b)`.

Therefore, your second statement should read:

> if *both* of the conditions *don't* fail, the user should be allowed to access [whatever]

Answer (score 0):

Well, here you are:

`$a && $b` means that the condition is true if `$a` and `$b` are set to true.

`$a || $b` means that `$a` or `$b` (or both) must be set to true.

`!$a && $b` means that `$a` must be `false` and `$b` must be `true`

`!$a || $b` means that `$a` must be `false` or `$b` must be `true`

`$a != $b` means that `$a` must be not equal to `$b`

`$a == $b` means that `$a` must be equal to `$b`

`$a > $b` means that `$a` must be greater than `$b`

`$a < $b` means that `$a` must be less than `$b`

and so on...

They are [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), check it out!

Answer (score 0):

In your first example your using the OR operator but expecting to match 2 conditions for the following code, but one or the other could be matched.

E.G so if the user is not user level 3 it will logout regardless if 
`$current_user_id != $session_user_id` or visa versa.

Using the AND operator means both conditions must be matched before logging out.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `$current_user_id = 3`, `$session_user_id = 5`, and `access_level($session_user_id) level = 3`. That means `$current_user_id != $session_user_id` is **true**, and `access_level($session_user_id) != 3` is **false**. `||` is **true** if either of the conditions is **true**, so the `if` succeeds and the user is logged out.

Or suppose `$current_user_id = 3`, `$session_user_id = 3`, and `access_level($session_user_id) level = 2`. That means `$current_user_id != $session_user_id` is **false**, and `access_level($session_user_id) != 3` is **true**. Again, this means the `||` is **true**, so the `if` succeeds and the user is logged out.